# Displaying different graphics in multiple OpenGL windows

Tags: c++, opengl

I got stuck with displaying multiple windows in openGL... That is if i display two windows, tranformation is not possible in both the windows... Is there any other way i can do it..???

Comment: can you please provide more details and be more specific? what language are you using?

Comment: I'm doin openGL graphics programming in visual C++... The language used is C++ with openGL functions...

Answer (score 2):

Each window should have it's own OpenGL context thus you will need to perform the same operations in each window for the views to stay consistent.  If you perform a geometry transformation when rendering in the first context it will only appear in the second context if it is explicitly executed in that second context.

More details on your setup and desired goals would be helpful.  On what platform and framework are you working?  Are you trying to render the same scene from different views in different windows or are you rendering different scenes in the different windows?

Comment: Actually i'm doin project in openGL using visual C++.. I'm trying to render different scenes in the different windows.. In the first window i'm trying to launch a rocket.. in second one trying to rotate the satellite around the erth....

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorial #42 of the NeHe OpenGL tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=42) shows how to have multiple viewports (which you can have in one window or multiple windows).

Also, here is some [source code](http://nehe.gamedev.net/counter.asp?file=data/downloads/L/llamagl_v2.zip) that is a modification of that tutorial using multiple windows.